# Ionic: Ng-change not always fired when input type is email

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-change

I started using the Ionic Framework. 
I use input fields with type text & email. When I use the `input=email`, the `ng-change` event isn't always fired. When typing text in the input `name`, the console tracks every letter that changes. In the input `email` the only way the `ng-change` event is fired is when filling in the input and deleting all the text that was entered. Did anybody had the same problem? Or with AngularJS?

**form.HTML**

```
   <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">{{"your_name" | translate}}</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="changeName()">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">{{"your_email" | translate}}</span>
      <input type="email" ng-model="mail" ng-change="changeEmail()">
  </label>
```

**form.JS**

```
$scope.changeName = function(){
  console.log("change name");
};


$scope.changeEmail = function(){
  console.log("change mail");
};
```

Many thanks!

Comment: it is only fired if the email is valid

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Thx man. Such a stupid question!